# Spring Boot not listening to external logging.level.* properties

Tags: spring-boot

I'm currently dealing with external logging properties for the application I'm building. I have a custom properties file called `myapp.properties`. It contains some custom properties and some environment-specific Spring properties like SSL and server port(including logging).

The custom properties file works just fine for all properties, except for the logging.level.* properties, which are just plainly ignored.

For example, when I use this property in my custom `myapp.properties`:

`server.port=12345`.

It works just fine: `s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 12345 (http)`

However, when I try the same thing for the logging properties:

`logging.level.root=ERROR`

It still logs other messages: `2017-05-10 12:32:54.984  INFO 9188 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)`.

Anyone knows what could possibly be a solution for this problem?

Comment: How have you told Spring Boot to use `myapp.properties`?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot initialises the logging system very early. So early, in fact, that a properties file that's configured via `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` isn't available in time.

You have a few options including:

- Configuring the logging level in the standard `application.properties` or `application.yml` files
- [Configuring `spring.config.name`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) so that Boot will look for `myapp.properties` either in addition to or in place of `application.properties`

Comment: Hi Andy, I was already afraid of that. I already fixed the issue by creating two custom properties, one for the root logging level, and one for our own package logging level. I change the log level at run time using these two properties.

Answer (score 0):

I asked, essentially, that question as issue on github. So here's solution.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9243